# Storing and retrieving large amount of coordinates (X, Y and Z) in a database (database choice)

Tags: database

I am working on a project where I need to store a large amount of X, Y, Z integers (coordinates) to a database, along with a session identifier and the unixtime.

This data will be server to a JavaScript client running the graphing library D3 via a REST service.

If I would use SQL, I would use a scheme like this:

```
INT PRIMARY id | VARCHAR(16) session | INT unixtime | SMALLINT x | SMALLINT y | SMALLINT z
```

I expect the data to be updated regulary (many single insert of a row), and when retrieved, all data belonging to a session identifier will be fetched.

Preferrably, to avoid caching all this data in a REST API client before passing it to the JavaScript client, it should be possible to fetch a smaller amount of them at a time.

My question is, what database technology would best fit my needs here?

Thanks

Comment: Not really a question for SO.

Comment: @OldProgrammer - What SE site will fit this question better?